# API or mechanism to apply SCC labels to EXOL mailbox items and folders?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

Is there an API, or other viable method, to programmatically apply O365 Security and Compliance Center **[Labels](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-labels-af398293-c69d-465e-a249-d74561552d30)** to folders or mail items on specific mailboxes in O365 Exchange Online?

The built in O365 SCC functionality to auto apply labels (assuming you even have E5 licensing - which we don't) is inadequate. We need the ability on a per mailbox basis to apply SCC labels to specific mail items and folders. Due to the quantity of items that has to be categorized this needs to be scripted.

I've looked at EWS and while it appears you can apply MRM policies I see nothing on applying SCC labels. I've looked at the Powershell APIs and while it appears you can create and modify labels, there is nothing that I found to actually apply those labels to mail items or folders on a specific mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to the MS product team for the SCC Labels it was determined that I could in fact use EWS to apply SCC labels the exact same way that I would set MRM labels.

Testing has validated that it works and we have deployed this into production.